# How to set default theme for LatinIME in AOSP

Tags: android, keyboard, themes, default, android-source

I need some guidance with setting default theme for LatinIME on AOSP. I am not quite sure where this value is stored.

First I tried setting the theme in ThemeSettingsFragment.java located in LatinIME. So now everytime a theme was set or changed it would always pick mine. Later on I found out this class is only called when we open Keyboard themes in Settings (Language & Input -> Android Keyboard (AOSP) -> Appearance & layouts -> Theme). Resulting in theme being changed only IF we opened these view. My goal is to have my theme set when I build AOSP.

Next I suspected the value could be stored in some global configuration and that led me to class InputMethodManagerService.java where I found constant Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD. But that didn't lead me anywhere worth while.

Anyone ever worked on something similar or knows the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try making changes here : https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_inputmethods_LatinIME/blob/cm-14.1/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/KeyboardTheme.java#L56-L58

I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer. I didn't test this properly, but now I can tell it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Haha. No issues :D

Answer (score 0):

[Sanyam Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6667328/sanyam-jain) is right to the point, adding few more details to it.
packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/keyboard/KeyboardTheme.java to be modified to change the default keyboard layout or you can add your custom layout there and also make sure the options added/changed correctly in packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/res/values/keyboard-themes.xml

In my case, I want material dark theme as default and first option in the keyboard layout settings. below are the changes I made,

1. KeyboardTheme.java

   public static final int DEFAULT_THEME_ID = THEME_ID_LXX_DARK;

   private static KeyboardTheme[] AVAILABLE_KEYBOARD_THEMES;

   ```
    /* package private for testing */
    static final KeyboardTheme[] KEYBOARD_THEMES = {
    new KeyboardTheme(THEME_ID_LXX_DARK, "LXXDark", R.style.KeyboardTheme_LXX_Dark,
                // This has never been selected as default theme.
                Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP),
        new KeyboardTheme(THEME_ID_ICS, "ICS", R.style.KeyboardTheme_ICS,
                // This has never been selected because we support ICS or later.
                VERSION_CODES.BASE),
        new KeyboardTheme(THEME_ID_KLP, "KLP", R.style.KeyboardTheme_KLP,
                // Default theme for ICS, JB, and KLP.
                VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH),
        new KeyboardTheme(THEME_ID_LXX_LIGHT, "LXXLight", R.style.KeyboardTheme_LXX_Light,
                // Default theme for LXX.
                VERSION_CODES.BASE),

    };
   ```

2. In keyboard-themes.xml

```html
<string-array name="keyboard_theme_names" translatable="false">
  <item>@string/keyboard_theme_material_dark</item>
  <item>@string/keyboard_theme_material_light</item>
  <item>@string/keyboard_theme_holo_white</item>
  <item>@string/keyboard_theme_holo_blue</item>
</string-array>
<!-- An element must be a keyboard theme id of
         {@link com.android.inputmethod.keyboard.KeyboardTheme#THEME_ID_ICS} etc. -->
<integer-array name="keyboard_theme_ids" translatable="false">
  <item>4</item>
  <item>3</item>
  <item>2</item>
  <item>0</item>
</integer-array>
```